# Do users of chess-db get informed when you play against their computer simulation of themselves?

Tags: engines, software, websites

If I were to play against the computer simulations of chess players that have an account on chess-db (titled or none titled I know), will they get informed that I trained or prepared against them by playing their computer simulation?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. Chess-db has no good way of contacting those people anyway.